# Task.WhenAll with fewer lines of code

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Using `Task.WhenAll` has a lot of benefits, but it at least doubles the LOC required to write something.

**Listing1**

```
var result1 = await SomeLongRunningOperation1().ConfigureAwait(false);
var result2 = await SomeLongRunningOperation2().ConfigureAwait(false);
var result3 = await SomeLongRunningOperation3().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Listing2**

```
var result1Task = SomeLongRunningOperation1();
var result2Task = SomeLongRunningOperation2();
var result3Task = SomeLongRunningOperation3();

await Task.WhenAll(
    result1Task,
    result2Task,
    result3Task)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var result1 = result1Task.Result;
var result2 = result2Task.Result;
var result3 = result3Task.Result;
```

Obviously Listing1 awaits the 3 operations one after another (3 x 10 seconds = 30 seconds), while Listing2 awaits the 3 operations at the same time (only 10 seconds for all 3).

However the code in Listing2 is much longer an harder to read.

My Question is:
Is it possible to write the logic of Listing2 with something as easy to read and as short as Listing1?

Comment: Put "result1Task result2Task result3Task" in array, and your code is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, this achieves the parallelism you're looking for and uses fewer lines of code than Listing 2:

```
var result1Task = SomeLongRunningOperation1();
var result2Task = SomeLongRunningOperation2();
var result3Task = SomeLongRunningOperation3();

var result1 = await result1Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
var result2 = await result2Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
var result3 = await result3Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It does have minor differences in timing - if `result1` is available significantly before `result2` or `result3` is available, it will be asigned earlier. But since you `await` all 3 tasks (and don't do anything with the results), you won't actually proceed past the assignment of `result3` until all three tasks have completed - exactly what you were asking for with your `WhenAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Tuple`s, but you'd have to construct helper methods for various arities. Here's such one for 3 arguments:

```
public static async Task<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2, Task<T3> t3)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var result1 = await t1.ConfigureAwait(false);
    var result2 = await t2.ConfigureAwait(false);
    var result3 = await t3.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Tuple.Create(result1, result2, result3);
}
```

Usage:

```
var results = await WhenAll(Operation1(), Operation2(), Operation3());
var result1 = results.Item1;
```

In C# 7 you could use the built-in tuple support so the tuple items would be named.

Answer (score 0):

If your operations all have the same result type, you could also do:

```
var task1 = SomeLongRunningOperation1();
var task2 = SomeLongRunningOperation2();
var task3 = SomeLongRunningOperation3();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3).ConfigureAwait(false);
```